# Height wont grow to max height even with height 100%

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have a button with an image inside. I want the button height to grow to the max height of 160px, but it isn't doing so. This also means the image isn't doing it, how can I solve this?

```css
.img-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  max-height: 160px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.img {
  max-height: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I would say that you should use height property, or in last case scenario to add min-height as well. I hope my comment helped.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'grow'. Is the image to maintain its aspect ratio but you can't allow the button to get higher than 160px or wider than 250px and the image is to fill either the width or the height?

Comment: remove height:100% and remove align-items:center

Answer (score 0):

max-height property defines the maximum height of an element.

If the content is larger than the maximum height, it will overflow. How the container will handle the overflowing content is defined by the overflow property.

If the content is smaller than the maximum height, the max-height property has no effect.

Since you only defined max height it does not define the min height, so either set height property or min-height property

Comment: I did set a height property. I just hoped max height on container and height 100% on child would work. I guess not.

Comment: @LeonMichalak height of image set to 100% means its 100% of the height of its parent, now  paretn in your case is img-btn whose max height is 160px, so that does not define its min height, and its height is based upon size of content inside it.